# How to determine httpd memory usage

Tags: memory, httpd, top

If I have this output from `top` for httpd, how do I determine its total memory usage?

```
16924 apache    20   0  203m 7108 2852 S  0.0  0.2   0:03.48 httpd                                                                                                                                                                           
16925 apache    20   0  204m 7128 2776 S  0.0  0.2   0:03.40 httpd                                                                                                                                                                           
16926 apache    20   0  203m 7024 2772 S  0.0  0.2   0:03.24 httpd                                                                                                                                                                           
16928 apache    20   0  203m 7164 2852 S  0.3  0.2   0:03.64 httpd                                                                                                                                                                           
16929 apache    20   0  203m 7028 2740 S  0.0  0.2   0:03.37 httpd                                                                                                                                                                           
16930 apache    20   0  203m 6828 2740 S  0.0  0.2   0:03.21 httpd                                                                                                                                                                           
16931 apache    20   0  203m 6916 2728 S  0.0  0.2   0:03.55 httpd                                                                                                                                                                           
16941 apache    20   0  204m 7076 2740 S  0.0  0.2   0:03.39 httpd                                                                                                                                                                           
16995 apache    20   0  203m 6852 2716 S  0.0  0.2   0:03.46 httpd                                                                                                                                                                           
17086 apache    20   0  203m 6988 2716 S  0.0  0.2   0:03.73 httpd                                                                                                                                                                           
17103 apache    20   0  203m 7028 2740 S  0.0  0.2   0:03.46 httpd                                                                                                                                                                           
17194 apache    20   0  204m 7276 2852 S  0.0  0.2   0:03.17 httpd                                                                                                                                                                           
17288 apache    20   0  204m 7176 2840 S  0.0  0.2   0:03.03 httpd                                                                                                                                                                           
18432 apache    20   0  203m 6980 2740 S  0.0  0.2   0:02.31 httpd                                                                                                                                                                           
18659 apache    20   0  203m 6972 2816 S  0.0  0.2   0:01.87 httpd                                                                                                                                                                           
19432 root      20   0  203m 7784 4356 S  0.0  0.2   2:53.45 httpd                                                                                                                                                                           
19686 apache    20   0  203m 6916 2728 S  0.0  0.2   0:01.67 httpd                                                                                                                                                                           
19698 apache    20   0  203m 7048 2840 S  0.0  0.2   0:01.78 httpd                                                                                                                                                                           
19699 apache    20   0  203m 6904 2740 S  0.0  0.2   0:01.93 httpd                                                                                                                                                                           
19700 apache    20   0  203m 7124 2860 S  0.0  0.2   0:02.00 httpd                                                                                                                                                                           
19710 apache    20   0  203m 6736 2740 S  0.3  0.2   0:01.96 httpd
```

According to my NewRelic monitoring, it's using just over 600MB at the above point in time.

Answer (score 1):

You don't, from `top`.  Its memory accounting is incomplete, at best (the `SWAP` column is totally whack).  Use [smem](http://www.selenic.com/smem/) to provide you with more appropriate memory statistics.